# Matplotlib: Figure controls (zoom, save, etc) disappear when figure too small

Tags: matplotlib

When a matplotlib figure is shrunk below a given size, the controls on the bottom disappear.  I want to save the figure, at the size that I have stretched it too, but it seems that I cannot, because the save button disappears when the figure is that small.  Is there any way around this, other than manually calling fig.savefig() in the code?

Edit: Backend is TkAgg

Answer (score 1):

Ah, well it turns out there are keyboard shortcuts to the controls.

You can press CTRL-S to save (even on Mac - not Command-S).

The full list of shortcuts is here: https://matplotlib.org/users/navigation_toolbar.html

Answer (score 1):

When using "Qt4Agg" or "Qt5Agg" as backend,

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use("Qt4Agg")
```

the navigation toolbar can be extended with the two small arrows as shown below.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Ah, thanks, I should have mentioned I'm using TkAgg backend and it the problem is different here... controls disappear altogether once the figure gets small enough.   Anyway, the solution seems to be to learn the keyboard shortcuts.